# Why won't the image load and show in html using Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to load a .png file in HTML, which is using Node JS but the file isn't loading, it just show a broken image pic.

Here is my JS code :

```
var fs = require('fs')
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function(req,res){
  fs.readFile('index.html',function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.end(data);
  })
}).listen(8080);
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<div>
<p>This is a test...</p>
<p><img src="images/Numbers.png" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The browser asks for `images/Numbers.png` and your server sends it `index.html`. You don't have any code that would send the image to the browser so the browser can't display it.